# Solving $\tan x \sin^2x=2\tan x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

$\tan x \sin^2 x = 2\tan x \implies \tan x \sin^2x - 2\tan x=0 \implies \tan x(\sin^2x - 2)=0$

$\tan x=0$ or $\sin^2 x-2=0 \implies \sin x=\pm \sqrt{2}$

My question is, why can't you divide by $\tan x$ in hte beginning: $\dfrac{\tan x \sin^2 x}{\tan x}=\dfrac{2\tan x}{\tan x} \implies \sin x=\pm \sqrt{2}$.

We lost the $\tan x=0$, but I'm not understanding why it's incorrect to divide by $\tan x$. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you get rid of it? When tan(x) is $0$ the equality is immediately true (0 on both sides). You want ALL x's for which the equality is true.

Comment: It's fine when you divide both side by $\tan x$, in that moment, you're just assuming that the $x$ value you are looking at in the equation is one such that $\tan x \neq 0$, e.g. $x=\pi/4$. As ir7 points out, the values $x$ where $\tan x=0$ is a solution. So it would be good to note first that when $\tan x=0$ you have a solution, make note of these $x$ values. Then proceed to the "case" where $\tan x$ is non-zero and divide both sides by $\tan x$ from here and proceed.

Comment: So long as you keep track of the fact that you're "losing" the solution $\tan(x) = 0$, then it's perfectly fine--you're just factoring (but saving a few written steps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we're given an equation of the form $A(x) = B(x)$, if $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ have a nonconstant common factor (say, $C(x)$), we always to consider the possibility that $C(x) = 0$. That would automatically mean that $A(x) = B(x) = 0$, and $\displaystyle \frac{A(x)}{C(x)} = \frac{B(x)}{C(x)} = \frac{0}{0}$, which is undefined.

Answer (score 7):

Put both on the same side of the equals sign:
$$
\tan x(\sin^2 x - 2)=0
$$
You know that a product is zero exactly if one (at least) of the factors is zero. So either $\tan x=0$ or $\sin^2x=2$, and of course the second possibility is impossible. So the only possibility is that $\tan x=0$, and you know when that happens. In a situation like this, it is unsafe and even illicit to divide by a function that has the possibility of becoming zero, as is the case with $\tan x$.